# Nginx : How to set 'limit_conn' and 'limit_req'?

Tags: nginx

I'm using nginx **version 1.6.2** on **ubuntu 14.04**

I've tried to input `limit_conn` and `limit_req` at configuration file with referencing [nginx documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_limit_req_module.html).

**Nginx is well working without `limit_conn` and `limit_req` option**.

Following are test cases of nginx configuration with log messages.

I don't know what is wrong with my code.

---

**Case 1** - full configuration

*`/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`*

```
http {
    ...
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
    ...
    limit_conn_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=conn_limit_per_ip:10m;
    limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=req_limit_per_ip:10m rate=5r/s;
    ...
}
```

*`/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/service.conf`*

```
server {
    ...
    location / {
        limit_conn conn_limit_per_ip 30;
        limit_req zone=req_limit_per_ip burst=5 nodelay;
        ...
    }        
    ...
}
```

*`log message`*

```
unknown limit_req_zone "req_limit_per_ip" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/service.conf
```

---

**Case 2** - remove `limit_req` from sites-enabled configuration file

*`/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`*

```
http {
    ...
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
    ...
    limit_conn_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=conn_limit_per_ip:10m;
    limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=req_limit_per_ip:10m rate=5r/s;
    ...
}
```

*`/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/service.conf`*

```
server {
    ...
    location / {
        limit_conn conn_limit_per_ip 30;
        ...
    }        
    ...
}
```

*`log message`*

```
the size 10485760 of shared memory zone "conn_limit_per_ip" conflicts with already declared size 0 in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

---

**Case 3** - remove `limit_conn` from sites-enabled configuration file

*`/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`*

```
http {
    ...
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
    ...
    limit_conn_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=conn_limit_per_ip:10m;
    limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=req_limit_per_ip:10m rate=5r/s;
    ...
}
```

*`/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/service.conf`*

```
server {
    ...
    location / {
        limit_req zone=req_limit_per_ip burst=5 nodelay;
        ...
    }        
    ...
}
```

*`log message`*

```
unknown limit_req_zone "req_limit_per_ip" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/service.conf
```

---

**Case 4** - remove all from sites-enabled configuration file

*`/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`*

```
http {
    ...
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
    ...
    limit_conn_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=conn_limit_per_ip:10m;
    limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=req_limit_per_ip:10m rate=5r/s;
    ...
}
```

*`/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/service.conf`*

```
server {
    ...
    location / {
        ...
    }        
    ...
}
```

*`log message`*

```
[OK] - nginx reloaded well
```

---

**Case 5** - remove `limit_req_zone` and `limit_req`

*`/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`*

```
http {
    ...
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
    ...
    limit_conn_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=conn_limit_per_ip:10m;
    ...
}
```

*`/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/service.conf`*

```
server {
    ...
    location / {
        limit_conn conn_limit_per_ip 30;
        ...
    }        
    ...
}
```

*`log message`*

```
the size 10485760 of shared memory zone "conn_limit_per_ip" conflicts with already declared size 0 in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

---

**Case 6** - remove `limit_conn_zone` and `limit_conn`

*`/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`*

```
http {
    ...
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
    ...
    limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=req_limit_per_ip:10m rate=5r/s;
    ...
}
```

*`/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/service.conf`*

```
server {
    ...
    location / {
        limit_req zone=req_limit_per_ip burst=5 nodelay;
        ...
    }        
    ...
}
```

*`log message`*

```
unknown limit_req_zone "req_limit_per_ip" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/service.conf
```

Comment: Make sure you don't have another thing messing with your http block in all the files included by your setup.

Answer (score 7):

### Solution

Merge `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/service.conf` into `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`. In other words, remove `service.conf` file and paste `server` block at `nginx.conf` file's `http` block. Here is code.

*/etc/nginx/nginx.conf*

```
http {

    ..

    limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=req_limit_per_ip:10m rate=2r/s;
    limit_conn_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=conn_limit_per_ip:10m;

    ..

    server {

        ..

        location / {
            limit_req zone=req_limit_per_ip burst=5 nodelay;
            limit_conn conn_limit_per_ip 30;
        }

        ..
    }
}
```

---

### Meaning of variables and Test

1. `limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=req_limit_per_ip:10m rate=2r/s` + `limit_req zone=req_limit_per_ip burst=5 nodelay`

   - Set shared memory as 10MB
   - Limit requests per IP as following
   - Set maximum requests as `rate * burst` in `burst` seconds
   - For example, maximum value is 10(=2*5) requests in 5 seconds in this case
   - With `nodelay` option : Nginx would return 503 response and not handle excessive requests
   - Without `nodelay` option : Nginx would wait (no 503 response) and handle excessive requests with some delay
2. `limit_conn_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=conn_limit_per_ip:10m` + `limit_conn conn_limit_per_ip 30`

   - Set shared memory as 10MB
   - Limit connections per IP as 30 in this case
   - Note that normal browser makes 2~8 connections and SPDY protocol split each connections
   - Nginx would return 503 response if connection exceeds this value

Comment: so if i put these values into the main nginx config file , it will applied globally to all other vhosts config files ?

Comment: Your understanding of the `burst` and `nodelay` directives is incorrect. If you set a rate of 10r/s Nginx returns 503 to reqs less than 100ms apart. The `burst` directive defines a maximum number of requests to queue, so if I make 30 reqs in 1 sec the last 20 will go in the burst queue, once the burst queue is full Nginx returns 503. `nodelay` forwards all reqs for processing immediately until the burst queue is full instead of one at a time at the set rate limit. In your example Nginx would accept 5 reqs simultaneously (burst now full), then 1 req every 500ms as the burst queue clears

Comment: As a complement to @miknik comment there is also a `delay=..` option in nginx configs which you can place it instead of `nodelay` option which activates "two stage rate limiting". You can find more details here to have a better point of view: https://www.nginx.com/blog/rate-limiting-nginx/

Answer (score 4):

The directives `limit_req_zone` and `limit_conn_zone` just need precede the corresponding directives included in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/service.conf`.

So in Case 1 just need to change `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` to:

```
http {
    ...
    limit_conn_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=conn_limit_per_ip:10m;
    limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=req_limit_per_ip:10m rate=5r/s;
    ...
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
    ...
}
```

See:

1. http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_limit_conn_module.html
2. http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_limit_req_module.html