# How to limit number of connections per IP on Nginx?

Tags: nginx

I use limit_conn_zone  and limit_conn directives ,in order to limit number of connections per IP to 10.

```
http{
  limit_conn_zone $binary_remote_addr   zone=perip:10m; 
  include mime.types;
  sendfile   on;    
  server {
    listen 80;
    server_name   wx110.cn;
    root /data/www/wx120;

    limit_conn  perip 10;

    location / {
      index  index.html ;
    }
  }
}
```

For testing if nginx.conf file work, I use ab test below  making 100 connections .I hope  90 of them would be failed

ab -n 100 -c 100 http://wx110.cn/test.html

but the result is :

```
Server Software: nginx/1.16.1
Server Hostname:wx110.cn

Concurrency Level:100
Time taken for tests:0.150 seconds
Complete requests: 100 
Failed requests: 0
```

Comment: Thanks for updating your question. Rather than tell us the way you want to solve the problem that isn't working, please edit the question to tell us what you're trying to achieve. It looks like you're trying to limit connections to Nginx - is this total connections or connections from a single IP. What isn't working? Is it not limiting connections at all? AB usually gives more output, are any parts of that output relevant?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Nginx : How to set 'limit\_conn' and 'limit\_req'?](https://serverfault.com/questions/660243/nginx-how-to-set-limit-conn-and-limit-req)

Answer (score 1):

According to your configuration, Nginx allows ten connections per second.
if you want to limit total connection to Nginx from  source IP do this:

it will only allow ten connection for single IP

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --syn --dport 80 -m connlimit --connlimit-above 10 --connlimit-mask 32 -j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset
```